# Apache beam splittable DoFn is not spreading work to multiple workers on Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I am Learning to use splittable DoFn. I expect my work to be distributed to 500 workers, but Dataflow only ran it with 1 or 2 workers. Am I understanding or implementing splittable DoFn incorrectly?

my beam version is 2.16.0

my DoFn

```
    class Calculate extends DoFn<String, String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ProcessElement
    public void process(ProcessContext c, RestrictionTracker<OffsetRange, Long> tracker) {
        for (long i = tracker.currentRestriction().getFrom(); tracker.tryClaim(i); ++i) {
            try {
                c.output(i + "_" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + "_" + Math.random() + "_" +  c.element());
                for (int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++ ) {
                    Math.sqrt(j);
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @GetInitialRestriction
    public OffsetRange getInitialRange(String element) {
        return new OffsetRange(1L, 50000000L);
    }
    @SplitRestriction
    public void splitRestriction(String element, OffsetRange restriction, OutputReceiver<OffsetRange> receiver) {

        for (long i = restriction.getFrom(); i < restriction.getTo(); i += 100000) {
            receiver.output(new OffsetRange(i, i + 100000));
        }

    }
   }
```

my main function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(PipelineOptions.class);
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    p.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://mybucket/EMEA/20200525/singleposition.csv"))
     .apply(ParDo.of(new Calculate()))
     .apply(TextIO.write().to("gs://mybucket/EMEA/20200525/obligor.csv"));

    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
  }
```

Comment: How many maximum workers did you specify in your Dataflow job?

Comment: I did not specify the number of workers. I tried to add --maxNumWorkers=10, but still at most 2 workers were used.

Answer (score 2):

I found two major gaps in your understanding.

1. How we can control number of worker in cloud dataflow (i.e. You want to spawn 500 workers for your Calculate() DoFn())?

> Cloud Dataflow offers 2 scaling algorithms.
>
> a) Throughput based : In this Dataflow service automatically chooses the appropriate number of worker instances required to run your job. However , you can restrict the maximum number of worker it will spawn using --max_num_workers.
>
> **Throughput based algorithm is the default setting for cloud dataflow.**
>
> b) None (--autoscaling_algorithm=NONE) : In this you can provide number of workers you want to spawn for your jobs manually. You can specify number of worker using --num_worker parameter.

***In your use case you're using default mode. Hence, you're getting only 2 worker depending upon your load.***

Read this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#Autotuning) for more detailed info.

2. What is Splittable DoFn() and When to use It?

> Consider following two use case for reading data from a source:
>
> **- Read filenames from Kafka and read each file using textIO (Bounded Source)**
>
> **- Read all the list of partition for a kafka topic and read data from each partition (Bounded Source)**
>
> The above use cases are really tricky to implement using ParDo (read old ParDO) because
>
> **ParDo fucntions are monolithic** - a single processElement() call, which can only output a bounded number of elements, but not provide progress or sizing information, accept parallelization hints, split, or checkpoint.
>
> **SDF is a DoFn with non-monolithic element processing -** when processing a single element, the runner can make requests to the SDF, in order to do the work associated with this element non-monolithically over multiple, possibly concurrent processElement() calls
>
> So, You can read multiple text files in parallel with Splittable DoFn for above explained use case.
>
> In addition to above you can refer these two docs for more details: [SDFProposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AQmx-T9XjSi1PNoEp5_L-lT0j7BkgTbmQnc6uFEMI4c/edit#), [dynamic balancing](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/no-shard-left-behind-dynamic-work-rebalancing-in-google-cloud-dataflow)

***Now in your scenario, I don't see any need of non-monolithic processing. You will not achieve any added performance benefit here by using SDF.***

Comment: My understanding is,  my DoFn has a loop of 50000000 times. If looping for 50000000 takes a long time and thus it is "monolithic", I think dataflow will consider the load is big enough to qualify a scaling.  And after scaling, say, scale to 1000 workers, and each worker do for 50000 loops, this can improve performance.   Is above understanding not correct ?